# What sort of user interface would you use for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, html, user-interface

I'm trying to make a user interface that would do the following but I'm clueless as to how to do it.

The problem is this, I want to let people allocate a percentage of their account balance to different thing, say you want to allocate 40% to rent, 30% for savings and 30% to everything else

How would you let people choose the percentage between these things?
the problem is the total percentage will have to be 100% all the time, so say you want to put 3 textboxes on the page each indicating the ratio,

If the user chooses 80% for the first one and 20% for the next one, then the last one must remain 0, it's an awkward user interface and considering how little attention Internet users give to the pages the browse, I don't think anyone will fully understand and use it...

I was thinking about sliders like an audio equalizer, but even that is hard to make sense out of.

A pie chart of some kind that can let you change the values by clicking on the pie chart would probably be a good idea, but very hard to implement in js.

Let me know what you think

Comment: Great question for ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk partitioning tools address the same problem I think, with their visualisation of available space, partitions inside it, unpartitioned space, etc. Have you ever used anything like Partition Magic or similar?

But - yes, it's quite challenging UI to create in JavaScript, but still doable.

[image]

Comment: A good idea to start with, though the difference between this and partitioning is that there is a spatial relation between the partitions.  That tiny gap at the far right is a true physical gap.  Percentages don't have such spatial relations.

Comment: Can't there be unallocated percentage of account balance (like 10%) or something? And then one still will need to manually decrease percentage on one item, until he is able to increase in on another.

Comment: Absolutely.  But what isn't shown by this screenshot is that those gaps can logically exist between each of the partitions for a partition manager.  For a percentage control, multiple "gaps" don't make sense.  That's what I mean by this being a good idea to start; it won't work identically.

Comment: Here's a tricky scenario: For the partition manager, it makes sense to make a "stretch" operation hard stop at the edge of another partition.  For a percentage control, it wouldn't.  What would the user expect when you click and drag on one of the borders, with no gap between them?  Would it subtract from one value to add to another, or subtract from the gap, and shift the middle value (leaving it the same)?  How would you handle 0% for one item, and still allow resizing?

Comment: I see. Well, empty spaces can stick to each other, like air bubbles. When increasing partition for one item, with available empty space, all other partitions may pop in direction of that empty space, while it is still available and stop, once it's not. For zero partitions there could be markers above and below. But yes, I agree, what I proposed is not a final UI for percentage task. It requires some work on it.

Answer (score 0):

How about three slider bars that update each other?

Or How about an Interactive Pie Chart?

Comment: Unfortunately the site is rarely in a state that is interactive (they only put a product out every several months, and then only for a week or two), but they had such a setup at: http://www.humblebundle.com/

Comment: Interactive pie chart sounds like a pain to code and sounds painful from a UX perspective, too.  Unless you have examples that we can check out, I wouldn't recommend going that route.  But having a secondary view as a pie chart that automatically updated via the sliders wouldn't be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

My vote is for sliders that update in real time; slider A is grabbed and, when changed, updates sliders B and C. You can have a pie chart update as well to reinforce what's going on.